# How to pass some of session variables to the logout page in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, session, spring-security, logout

I need to take a customer survey after a user has logged out. How to pass some of the session variables (user info) to the logout page so they can be rendered by Thymeleaf? During logout a session is invalidated and all session variables are removed.

**UPDATE**

To start with - a couple of ideas that are not ideal:

- pass variables as URL parameters to the logout page so Thymeleaf can render whatever it needs for the survey
- create "pre-logout" page that is rendered with session variables and that executes immediate AJAX request to logout.
- pass as a URL-parameter a variable that is a reference to the database. The reference would allow the Spring to retrieve all stored parameters in the database and pass it as model to the view for further rendering. Would have to encrypt the parameter and provide timestamp for invalidation of unused ones.

Now - are there any other (better) ideas?

Thanks,

**UPDATE 2 - SOLUTION**:

1. In WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter I changed logout so it does not invalidate session.
2. I extended LogoutController and overrode onLogoutSuccess(...). So it retrieves some of session variables, stores them temporarily as local variables, invalidates the session and puts into a new session as session attributes. All other variables are gone.
3. In MVC-controller - I retrieve the session attributes from HttpServletRequest and put them into MVC model; after which I delete the session attributes. :D. It works.

Comment: can you access session object ?

Comment: @Ravi - this is after logout redirect, so nothing is valid there.

Comment: then you have already answered your question. :)

Comment: @Ravi - Not really. There are workarounds - eg. could possibly add "pre-login page" that immediately after rendering submits background AJAX call to logout and kill the session.

Comment: @Ravi - got the solution. create a new session for logout and throw the perviously stored variables into there... (see the update).